# Some text lowered in Eclipse RCP app on Mac OS X 10.10+

Tags: eclipse-rcp, jface

On Mac OS X 10.10+, the text in some but not all controls appears to be lowered.

For example, on the left-hand-side of the standard Preferences dialog in my Eclipse RCP application, the preference page titles appear lowered significantly.

They're lowered so far that the descenders of the font are cut off. For example, observe the tail of the "p" in "Help."

As another example, observed by @greg-449, the text is also lowered in the buttons in the same dialog.

**Observations:**

- The problem does not occur on prior versions of Mac OS X.
- The problem does not occur on Windows.
- The bounding box appears correct, as indicated by the highlighted selection area.
- I'm building atop Eclipse RCP 4.5.
- The problem ***does not*** occur in the Eclipse IDE's Preferences dialog, in Eclipse 4.5.1 and 4.4.2.
- I've tried using CSS Spy in the Eclipse IDE's Preferences dialog. Although it works in the main window, it does not work for me in the Preferences dialog, at least when using the same keyboard shortcut.
- The text is larger and positioned well in buttons in dialogs provided by the operating system, like "File>Open."
- In a custom dialog not pictured here, the text in custom buttons is centered well, but the text in the OK/Cancel buttons provided by Eclipse is lowered.

Since the titles appear correctly in the IDE, it seems like there must be something we can do to make them appear correctly in my application.

***Question: What do I need to do differently to avoid the lowered title text?*** Even clues of where to start would be appreciated.

Here's a snapshot of the problem in my application:

[image]

Comment: I am seeing the same on one of my e4 RCPs (another uses different fonts and is OK!). Update: weirdly running my RCP again it doesn't get the problem the second time!

Comment: @greg-449 - I'm getting the same behavior every time. Thanks for your earlier observation that the text is also lowered in some other controls. I'll edit the question to reflect that. As far as I can tell our *.css file does not specify a system font explicitly, nor does any of our code.

Comment: I reproduced this defect in a SSCCE generated by Eclipse's plug-in template "RCP 3.x Mail Template," and submitted it to Eclipse in [Bug 481144 - Text lowered badly on Mac 10.10+ -- AKA "Lowered Textpectations"](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=481144).

Comment: The [Eclipse bug above](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=481144) has been marked resolved for upcoming Eclipse release 4.6.3.